# Adding buttons in a StatusBar via FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, statusbar, controlsfx

How can I add buttons using FXML to ControlsFX [`StatusBar`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/StatusBar.html)?

This is how my status bar is created in my fxml:

```
<StatusBar fx:id="statusBar" onMouseEntered="#openSomething" onMouseExited="#closeSomething"/>
```

I saw I can add buttons to this status bar but I have no idea how to add buttons to the status bar via FXML. I tried adding buttons via java code and this works fine. Like this:

```
statusBar.getLeftItems().add(new Button("Info"));
```

But I want to add the via FXML.

Comment: Just do exactly the same thing in FXML: `<StatusBar ...><leftItems><Button text="Info"/></leftItems></StatusBar>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of a `StatusBar` in `FXML`:

```xml
<StatusBar fx:id="mainStatusBar" text="This is a StatusBar" progress=".314">
    <leftItems>
        <Button text="L Button 1"/>
        <Button text="L Button 2"/>
    </leftItems>
    <rightItems>
        <Button text="R Button"/>
        <ComboBox/>
    </rightItems>
    <graphic>
        <ImageView>
            <Image url="@/icons/sb.png"/>
        </ImageView>
    </graphic>
</StatusBar>
```